# The TypeConverter for "FontWeight" does not support converting from a string

Tags: .net, silverlight, xaml, visual-studio-2012, typeconverter

After installing Visual Studio 2012 and opening a Silverlight 5 project I'm getting various *design time* errors related to TypeConverter, such as:

> The TypeConverter for "FontWeight" does not support converting from a string.
>
> The TypeConverter for "Point" does not support converting from a string.
>
> The TypeConverter for "Thickness" does not support converting from a string.

That's not an exhaustive list, however.

Examples of these being:

`<Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />`

`<RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.5,0.5"> ...`

`<Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />`

Am I missing something obvious here, or is this a bug?

Comment: I'm getting this as well - projects build and execute fine, but theses messages are extremely annoying as they clutter up the XAML code view.

Comment: I have 2012 and I don't get this, I don't know why you would - sounds like a bug. I am working in SL4 however... may be a SL5 thing.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645047(v=vs.95).aspx  does your solution define any type converters, or is this referring to built in library converters?  if you have defined your own converters, make sure they implement CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext, Type) and it returns true.  If the error messages are about framework/library converters, then you may have legacy dlls linked.  Have you tried this on a new machine that has only ever had VS2012 (not 2010) installed?  Does this happen with a brand new SL5 project or only an existing one that was created with 2010?

Comment: I'm not defining any of my own type converters.

Comment: Whoops, too slow to edit my above comment: I've confirmed that I'm only referencing up-to-date SL5 framework dlls. This also occurs on my colleague's new machine, with only 2012 installed. My project was originally created in VS2010 (SL4), and and was upgraded to SL5 sometime prior to switching to VS2012. It doesn't appear to happen with a brand new project.

Comment: guess you could create the same project structure (add same references and files) at another NEW project in the same solution) and then use WinMerge or similar Diff tool to compare the two project files

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem: defined in the resources section

```
<UserControl.Resources>
  <local:MyConverter x:Key="myConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

In the XAML UE, I had to change

```
...Width="{Binding BindingProperty, Converter=myConverter}"...
```

to

```
...Width="{Binding BindingProperty, Converter={StaticResource myConverter}..."
```

Comment: All of my converters are already referenced with StaticResource, so unfortunately this isn't a fix for me.

Answer (score 1):

Got a simular problem:

`The TypeConverter for "Thickness" does not support converting from a string`

No Converters used in this XAML file

It's a silverlight project (Prism) who has been converted from SL4 to SL5. But there seems to be more going on, I also get errors like this:

`The specified value cannot be assigned to the collection. The following type was expected: "Inline".`

When TextBlock is used like this:

`<TextBlock>Hello</TextBlock>`

To get rid of that error:

`<TextBlock Text="Hello" />`

Its a bit cumbersome to start the application to see the result of XAML changes

Comment: As usual the Windows documentation  on this lacks examples. I gave up and just added the property I want to my class so a converter is no longer needed. Can't justify wasting any more time on it when there is a work-around.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it was driving me mad! For me it had to do with the Silverlight Toolkit, once I added that I started getting tons of these errors.

In my project file (right-click->Edit project file) I had referenced the toolkit dll like this (relative to source dir in my case):

```
<Reference Include="System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit">
    <HintPath>..\..\..\Bin\System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Changing it to this seemed to sort it (I'm not sure if internals is needed too but a new project with SL5 and toolkit added seemed to ref it):

```
<Reference Include="system.windows.controls.toolkit, Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
<Reference Include="System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit.Internals, Version=4.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
```

Hope that helps,
John